# How can I show error message when wrong password or username?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, redux, mern

How can I show an error message if the username or password input is not the same on MongoDB? I don't know if my approach is right and I have been having trouble fixing this.

How can I show to the UI if the *loginFailure()* dispatch function kicks in? How can I render it to the UI telling the user if it works or not.

like warning error of

> wrong username or password

login.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
import { login } from '../../redux/apiCalls'
import './login.css'

const Login = () => {
    const [username, setUsername ] = useState("")
    const [password, setPassword ] = useState("")
    const history = useHistory()
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    
    const handleClick =(e) =>{
        e.preventDefault()
           if(login(dispatch,{username,password})){
             setTimeout(function(){
                 window.location.reload();
                 },500);
                console.log("Hello")
     
           }
           else{
               console.log("Erorr")
           }
    }


    return (
        <div className="login">
            <input type="text" placeholder="username" onChange={e=>setUsername(e.target.value)} />
            <input type="password" placeholder="password" onChange={e=>setPassword(e.target.value)} />
            <button onClick={handleClick}>submit</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

userRedux.js

```
export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState: {
    currentUser: null,
    isFetching: false,
    error: false,
  },
  reducers: {
    loginStart: (state) => {
      state.isFetching = true
    },
    loginSuccess: (state, action) => {
      state.isFetching = false
      state.currentUser = action.payload
    },
    loginFailure: (state) => {
      state.isFetching = false
      state.error = true
    },
    logout: (state) => {
      state.currentUser = false
    },
  },
})
export const { loginStart, loginSuccess, loginFailure, logout } =
  userSlice.actions
export default userSlice.reducer
```

apicalls.js

```
export const login = async (dispatch, user) => {
  dispatch(loginStart())
  try {
    const res = await publicRequest.post('/auth/login', user)
    dispatch(loginSuccess(res.data))
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(loginFailure())
   window.alert('Wrong password or Username')
  }
}
```

Using windows.alert("wrong pass or username"), it's working but is it possible that I can render a Ui for this? instead of popup boxes?

loginAuth.js

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username })
    !user && res.status(401).json('Wrong username')

    const hashedPassword = CryptoJS.RC4.decrypt(
      user.password,

      process.env.SECRET_KEY
    )
    const OriginalPassword = hashedPassword.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
    OriginalPassword !== req.body.password &&
      res.status(401).json('Wrong password')

    const accessToken = jwt.sign(
      {
        id: user.id,
        isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
      },
      process.env.JWT_SEC,
      { expiresIn: '3d' }
    )

    const { password, ...others } = user._doc

    res.status(200).json({ ...others, accessToken })
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(error)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to set a piece of state like;

`const [loginErr, setLoginErr] = useState(false);`

Then, when your login function returns false you can do;

```
    const handleClick =(e) =>{
        e.preventDefault()
           if(login(dispatch,{username,password})){
             setTimeout(function(){
                 window.location.reload();
                 },500);
                console.log("Hello")
     
           }
           else{
               setLoginErr(true);
           }
    }
```

Then, have a conditional render; this could be a component or just a div saying the error you with to display like;

```
<>
  { loginErr ? <SomeError /> : null }
</>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar solution like using setstate but `login(dispatch,{username,password})` will always return some value so it will always execute the if block only. What you can do is if you are storing the user in local storage then

```
const handleClick =(e) =>{
    e.preventDefault()
       login(dispatch,{username,password})
       if(JSON.parse(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"))){
         setTimeout(function(){
             window.location.reload();
             },500);
            console.log("Hello")
 
       }
       else{
           setLoginErr(true);
       }
}
```

then you can use the conditional display like

```
{ loginErr && <p>Invalid credentials</p> }
```

or else if use context then you can

```
const {user} = useContext(AuthContext)
const handleClick =(e) =>{
e.preventDefault()
   login(dispatch,{username,password})
   if(user){
     setTimeout(function(){
         window.location.reload();
         },500);
        console.log("Hello")

   }
   else{
       setLoginErr(true);
   }
```

}

and use the same conditional rendering